# jQuery grep gripes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filtering

According to the `$.grep()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) I would think that the code below would print `2`. But instead it's printing `0,1,2`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fSLW/13/). Am I going loco?

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2];

$.grep( arr, function(n,i) {
    return n > 1;
});

$('body').html( arr.join() );
```

Comment: Here's the fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/FZuVX/9/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.grep` returns a **new array** - it doesn't modify your existing one.

You want

```
arr = $.grep( arr, function(n,i) {
    return n > 1;
});
```

Check out the [$.grep docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) for more information

Comment: That's it! Thx. So it works similar to `$.map()`, not `$.each()`

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a key part.

"Description: Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected."

```
var newArray = $.grep( arr, function(n,i) {
    return n > 1;
});

$('body').html( newArray.join() );
```

Comment: Nice thanks -- I think it was the examples at the bottom that confused me then b/c they make it sound like it's the opposite. Plus I learned PHP first and PHP's `array_filter` returns the same array so I guess I throught it was the same.